# .ttf file causing build error in Travis CI

Tags: python, css, flask, twitter-bootstrap-3, travis-ci

During travis CI build,this error takes place

> 127.0.0.1 -"GET /static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>
> No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
> ...
>
> The build has been terminated

Travis.yml

```
language: python3
sudo: required
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - python-dev
python:
  - '3.5'

before_install:
- sudo apt-get -qq update
- sudo apt-get -y install librsvg2-bin
- sudo apt-get -y install pdftk 
- sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
- sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv

install:
- virtualenv  -p python3 flask_env
- source flask_env/bin/activate
- pip3 install -r requirements/test.txt
- pip3 install -r requirements/dev.txt

before_script:
- chmod +x ./start_server.sh

script:
- sh start_server.sh
- python -m pyflakes .

deploy:
- provider: releases
  skip_cleanup: true
  api_key:
    secure: ....
  file: "all-badges.pdf"
  on:
    branch: master

after_success:
- deactivate
- 'bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)'
```

Testing is done using selenium in python

The .ttf file is presented in the given place.Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: You should show us your entire travis.yml and full log. Your paste is almost meaningless without more context.

Comment: @renemilk Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line isn't an error:

```
127.0.0.1 -"GET /static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It just happens to be the last line of output that your build produces. The problem is likely here:

```
script:
- sh start_server.sh
```

I assume this starts a server process that listens for incoming requests and never stops unless signaled to do so. Travis executes commands in serial. It will wait for each command to terminate until either the entire workflow finishes or it times-out.

If you need the server to be running to execute your tests, you should run your server as a service or daemon (or invoke it as a background job).

Comment: Also, since you're apparently running a flask app, you can look into using ```pytest-flask``` to integrate server handling/setup into actual pytest code. And pyflakes too. That would free you from manually starting/stopping a server outside of the tests.